# Techniques for computing integrals on $G/K$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, integration

**Edit: I originally tried writing a simpler question, but to make more clear what I want I wrote the general question below**

Let $G$ be a compact group with compact subgroup $K\subseteq G$ (everything over $\mathbb{R}$, finite-dimensional).

Then the homogeneous space $G/K$ has a unique invariant volume form up to scalar, call it $\omega$.  I am interested in techniques for computing $\int\limits_{G/K}f\omega$, where $f$ is a $K$-invariant function on $G/K$.

Let $T'\subseteq K$ be a maximal torus of $K$, and let $T\subseteq G$ be a maximal torus of $G$ containing $T'$.

My question is: are there any known techniques for computing this integral by reduction to an integral over $T/T'$ via some result like in the Weyl integral formula?

I would expect that
$$
\int\limits_{G/K}f\omega=\int\limits_{T/T'} u(t)\cdot f|_{T/T'}\omega_{T/T'}
$$
where $\omega_{T/T'}$ is an invariant volume form on $T/T'$ (depending on $\omega$), $f|_{T/T'}$ is the restriction of $f$  to $T/T'$, and $u(t)$ is some function on $T/T'$ that depends on the particular form of $G/K$.

One can think of the Weyl integral formula then as the case when we take $G\times G/G$.

Comment: Even the case $K=\{1\}$ is nontrivial.   You need to specify  which volume form on $\omega$ you are using. Saying that it is unique up to a multiplicative constant won't help. To see how this is done for $K=\{1\}$ see MacDonald's 1980 Inventiones  paper *The volume of a compact Lie group*

Comment: If $\mu$ (resp. $\nu$) is a Haar measure on $G$ (resp. $H$), and $\lambda$ is the quotient measure on $G/H$, then $\lambda (G/H)=\mu (G)/\nu (H)$, so that you are reduced to the group case.

Comment: Hi @LiviuNicolaescu, thank you for your comment!  I have edited the question in a way that hopefully makes it more interesting.  I probably should I have written it this way at first, but I was trying to keep it 'simple'.  Let me know your thoughts!

Comment: @PaulBroussous thank you as well, let me know your thoughts.